# Moving from https://... to http:// without breaking links (SSL migration)

Tags: ssl

We hosted an event and sold tickets on our website. SSL was very necessary of course. Now the event is over and we're not taking in data that sensitive anymore. Is there a way to downgrade to from SSL to just plain HTTP without breaking links that might be out there with the 's' in 'https' in them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need the server to at least accept the request before it an redirect and it will show an error without a valid certificate.

I would leave it as is, is there a huge overhead in leaving an existing SSL based site in place.

Comment: Well, my host is shutting down. My new host requires a Wildcard SSL. So $90 per year if I buy a three year from RapidSSL.